# how to create a dataframe which will give the summary of multiple dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple CSV in a folder which I am reading as a data frame which further I am looping in a for loop

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"year":[2008,2008,2009,2008,2009],
            "product":["wood","paper","rocks","rocks","mint"],
            "cost":[200,300,90,78,300]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"year":[2008,2008,2009,2008,2009],
            "product":["grass","wood","mint","sand","bottle"],
            "cost":[900,309,908,178,90]})
```

I want to create a  data frame named "summary_report" while looping these data frames and store in summary_report dataframe.

Ignore colors

[image]

**Expected Report**:

A summary which has a unique count of a product and cost of it each year in column and data frame name in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with new columns for distinguish each DataFrame, then pass to [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (pd.concat([df1.assign(g = 'df1'), df2.assign(g = 'df2')])
        .groupby(['g','year'])
        .agg(product_count=('product', 'size'),
             cost_total=('cost','sum'))
        .stack()
        .unstack([1,2]))
print (df)
year          2008                     2009           
     product_count cost_total product_count cost_total
g                                                     
df1              3        578             2        390
df2              3       1387             2        998
```

EDIT:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(file).assign(g = f'df{i}') 
       for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir(path), 1) if ".csv" in file]


df = (pd.concat(dfs)
        .groupby(['g','year'])
        .agg(product_count=('product', 'size'),
             cost_total=('cost','sum'))
        .stack()
        .unstack([1,2]))
```

Comment: Cant do it beacuse i am looping files in a for loop, so at a time i only gonna have one file which i need to get a stats on then store it in a list and then for loop would take 2nd file a do the same ... and after that pd.concat may help out . Can we have this approach?

Comment: dfs= [file for file in os.listdir(path) if ".csv" in file ] .... for i in dfs than furtur process . and this is how i am reading files